# "Proper" idiom for handling multiple types in ruby arguments

Tags: ruby

So I am quite new to Ruby and still learning idioms. I still have a strong static-typing mindset, so maybe one problem is that I'm over-typing. Anyway, my situation is this.

I have an object called a Gene,with :name and :id.
I have another object called a Genotype, which maintains an array of Gene.

I'd like to check whether a given Genotype contains a given Gene. I'd like to able to pass Genotype.has_gene? a gene name, a gene id, or an actual Gene. In the former cases, the routine will match on name OR id, whichever is passed. If a full Gene is passed, the routine will insist on a match on both values.

My logic is to check whether the passed value is an Integer, in which case I assume it's an id; else check if it's a String and assume it's a name; else check whether it's a Gene; else complain and bail.

The code looks like this:

```
def has_gene?( gene )
      if gene.is_a? Integer
        id = gene
        name = ""
      elsif gene.is_a? String
        id = nil
        name = gene
      elsif gene.is_a? Gene
        id = gene.id
        name = gene.name
      else
        raise "Can't intepret passed data as gene information"   
      end
      name_valid = false
      id_valid = false
      @gene_specs.each do |current_gene_spec|
        current_gene = current_gene_spec.gene 
        name_valid = name.empty? || name == current_gene.name
        id_valid = id.nil? || id == current_gene.id
        break if name_valid && id_valid
       end
       return name_valid && id_valid
    end
```

Something feels wrong here but I can't pin it down. It seems to lack Ruby's famous conciseness :-)

Thoughts?

Comment: Why would you accept `String` and `Integer` if what you're looking for is a `Gene`? Testing against types is a really bad code smell.

Comment: If you're doing this sort of thing a lot then adding `to_gene` methods into `Fixnum`, `String`, `Gene`, `Symbol`, `NilClass`, ... might be an option; then you could simply `@gene_specs.include?(gene.to_gene)`. That's a big *if* and *might* so just a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Well, a Gene is really just a packaging of an Integer and String. So valid inputs would be Integer, String, or Integer-and-String, i.e. Gene. But regardless, my recognition of the bad smell was what led to the post :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would simplify it.  You could also use duck-typing if you want, but I think it would make the code more complicated.

```
def genes
  @gene_specs.collect &:gene
end

def has_gene?(x)
  case x
  when Integer
    genes.any? { |g| g.id == x }
  when String
    genes.any? { |g| g.name == x }
  when Gene
    genes.include?(x)   # assumes that Gene#== is defined well
  else
    raise ArgumentError, "Can't intepret passed data as gene information" 
  end
end
```

By default, Ruby will compare objects by identity (i.e. their location in memory), but for the Gene class you might want to do something different like this:

```
class Gene
  def ==(other)
    return false unless other.class == Gene
    id == other.id
  end
end
```

It pays off to spend some time studying the methods in [Ruby's Enumerable module](http://blog.davidegrayson.com/2012/03/ruby-enumerable-module.html).

Comment: Your intuition that I need to study Enumerable turns out to be dead on. Thanks for the cheat sheet on that as well.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby has methods to coerce values into basic objects, eg [Kernel#Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Array). We can use this to coerce a value into a sensible array:

```
Array(nil) # => []
Array(10) # => [10]
Array("hello") # => ["hello"]
Array([1, 2, 3]) # => [1, 2, 3]
```

This allows us to write very Rubyish methods that are flexible in the type of inputs they take without spending a lot of space checking types. Consider this contrived example:

```
def say_hello(people)
  people = [people] if people.is_a?(Person)

  people.each { |p| puts "Hello, #{p.name}" }
end

def say_hello(people)
  Array(people).each { |p| puts "Hello, #{p.name}" }
end
```

For your case, rather than adding a `Gene` method to `Kernel`, I suggest adding a class method to do coercion:

```
class Gene
  def self.coerce(geneish)
    case geneish
    when Gene
      geneish
    when Integer
      new(id: geneish)
    when String
      new(name: geneish)
    else
      raise ArgumentError, "Can't coerce #{geneish.inspect} into a Gene"
    end
  end
end

def has_gene?(gene)
  gene = Gene(gene)

  name_valid = false
  id_valid = false
  @gene_specs.each do |current_gene_spec|
    current_gene = current_gene_spec.gene 
    name_valid = gene.name.empty? || gene.name == current_gene.name
    id_valid = gene.id.nil? || gene.id == current_gene.id
    break if name_valid && id_valid
  end
  return name_valid && id_valid
end
```

I've left the rest of your `has_gene?` method intact, though several of the other answers here have good suggestions for using some `Enumerable` methods to clean it up.

Answer (score 1):

Even though ruby doesn't enforce types for method parameters, it's still a bad practice to allow multiple types for one parameter unless there are good reasons. It would be clearer if you provided three separate methods:

```
def has_gene?( gene)
  ...
end

def has_gene_with_id?( id)
  ...
end

def has_gene_with_name?( name)
  ...
end
```

Comment: I wanted to consolidate them because my logic for checking was cumbersome -- explicitly loop over the items in the array and check each one. As @DavidGrayson pointed out, if I knew Enumerable better I could (and will) reduce those checks to one-liners. Still, I do like the economy of the all-in-one method he demonstrated above.

Comment: I do not think allowing multiple types is bad practice.  It should be used sparingly though, and only for methods that need it.  The `link_to` method of Ruby on Rails is a great example of a versatile method that takes many different types of arguments.  Also, extending @lassej's pattern to a method that takes two independently flexible arguments would be pretty ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is not only dynamically typed, but it adheres to the *duck typing* paradigm which states:

> When I see a bird that walks like a duck and swims like a duck and quacks like a duck, I call that bird a duck.

What does it means? It means that in Ruby you shouldn't really care (unless in specific situation) if an Object is of the exact `X` class. You should care if it behaves like an `X` object.

How do you check it? The most famous method to check if a specific object behaves like you want to is to use the [`#respond_to?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F). This method will check if a method can be called on an object.

From there you can just check if the object responds to a method in the form of `#to_x` where `x` is the name of the class (even custom classes) and just call it to convert any type into the class you are going to need. So for example if you expect only a string to be used inside a method you can do:

```
def a_method( string )
    unless (string.respond_to? :to_str) // trigger error
    string = string.to_str
    // use string
end
```

This way, if I'm defining a special type `Duck` like:

```
class Duck

    def to_str
        // internally convert Duck to String
    end

    ...

end
```

I can pass it to your function:

```
obj = Duck.new
a_method( obj )
```

and it would work like expected by both me and the *designer* of `a_method`, without even knowing each other.

Comment: For strings, I think the better choice is to use `to_str`, because every object has a `to_s`.

Comment: You should use `to_str` and `to_int` here, not `to_s` and `to_i`. The former mean "IS-A" (which is what you want here), the latter mean "has a not completely stupid representation as", which is most definitely *not* what you want here. For example, `nil` is most certainly not a string, but it *does* have a not completely stupid string representation as the empty string.

Comment: However, note that using `respond_to?` is not duck typing, it's *chicken typing*, because you are afraid that someone might pass in the wrong object.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a method which accepts a block, allowing the user of the class to specify what to look for:

```
Gene = Struct.new(:name, :id)
class Genotype
  def initialize
    @arr=[]
  end
  def add(gene)
    @arr << gene
  end
  def any?(&block)
    @arr.any?(&block)
  end
end

gt = Genotype.new
gt.add Gene.new('a',0)
gt.add Gene.new('b',1)
p gt.any?{|g| g.name == "john"} #false
p gt.any?{|g| g.values == ["b",1]} #true
```